# jwsmtp library with Dev C++

Tags: c++, smtp

I am trying to use [jwsmtp library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwsmtp/) with dev c++ but I get linker errors. Anybody know how to use it with dev c++?, actually I have to send an email with attachment from my c program so I am trying to use it, but if anyone have alternative it will also be appreciated.

```
   [Linker error] main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `jwsmtp::mailer::send()'
```

Comment: Check out all the alternatives mentioned [C SMTP Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example) and [Send Email with C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298762/send-email-with-c) for starters.

Comment: ya i searched on google too much but no success in finding code with email attachments

Comment: Did you try searching for `undefined reference`? Also consider switching to VC++ Express.

Comment: i have not use visual c++ i think its complex dev c easy to use more powerful ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message you are getting, it seems like the library is not properly linked with your program. So please make sure that JWSMTP is included in your final executable. Properly link the library and you will be good to go. Go to the compiler option of Dev C++ and add your library path there if it isn't done already [In my version of Dev C++ Ide it is located at Menu -> Tools -> Compiler options -> Directories Tab -> Libraries] 
[Btw I dont have the reputation to comment.:( So I'm posting this as an answer. I'll delete this if this is not solving your problem]

Comment: i added the jwsmtp.lib and linked to project but still it give linker error  i think dev c++ have .a .o types libs the lib i found for jwsmtp is .lib extension   so anybody know how to convert it to .a or .o form

Comment: If you can compile the jwsmtp source code using gcc [use gcc -c] or other similar compilers you will get the .o [object] files. Try putting those files in Dev C++ lib path.

Comment: k downlaoding cygwin and hope i get object files

Comment: @DarkCorp: Best of luck... Meantime you may find this useful.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337949/whats-the-difference-between-lib-and-a-files

Comment: i created objects files of jwsmtp source code mailer.cpp , base64.cpp compat.cpp (mailer.o , base64.o , compat.o) then  i add their paths   in project options > parameters>linker    ..........   now getting again linker errors but a lot ...  also i tried this i add this to linker g++-jwsmtp  but it give error that  g++-jwsmtp: No such file or directory.

Comment: In the library folder `jwsmtp-1.32.15\docs` [assuming you are using the latest version] there is a file usage.html which describes about using the library in our programs [check other files in that folder too]. Pls check those.

Comment: well am improved  i compile code with cgywin and g++ compiler i get .a libs also i compiled the demo programs too but in dev c its not working i imported .a libs too

Comment: @DarkCorp : Glad that you are progressing well :)

Comment: finally i linked jwsmtp with dev c++ :D  now problem is it cant send mail   i set smtp server to smtp.gmaile.com and port to 465    but no sending mails

Comment: i think this library cant support ssl