# C++ code to send email from within a dll

Tags: c++, email, dll

I compiled a c++ *.dll file in Visual Studio 2015, and now I need to add a piece of code that will let me send some info to an email account (through Gmail, Outlook, I don't mind).  The address is fixed and the body will contain some variables from the cpp code. I found c++ code that can send emails (f.e. here: [Send Email with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298762/send-email-with-c)), but doubt whether this is optimal for a dll.
Any input?

Comment: Putting the code into a DLL doesn't make much (if any) real difference in how you want to write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAPISendMailW()` which is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh707275(v=vs.85).aspx