# How to send email using c++ (curl)

Tags: c++, email, curl, send

How to add Subject to this email?

```
    #include <windows.h>

int main(void){
    char* command = "curl smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 -v --mail-from \"SENDER.EMAIL@gmail.com\" --mail-rcpt \"RECEIVER.EMAIL@gmail.com\" --ssl -u SENDER.EMAIL@gmail.com:PASSWORD -T \"ATTACHMENT.FILE\" -k --anyauth";
    WinExec(command, SW_HIDE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this not working?  If so, how?

Comment: you might get some help over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856422/7516643)

Comment: My understanding is that there are `curl` libraries you can use, rather than going through system commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to send mail with subject in **cURL**: Command Line and From C++ code.

**Command Line:**

The subject can be specified in email data text file "email.txt"

```
curl smtp://mail.example.com --mail-from myself@example.com --mail-rcpt
receiver@example.com --upload-file email.txt
```

Here is the tutorial: [cURL_SMTP_Command_Line](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-smtp.html)

**From C++ code:**

In this case you specify Subject in payload_text.

```
  static const char *payload_text[] = {
  "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
  "To: " TO_MAIL "\r\n",
  "From: " FROM_MAIL "\r\n",
  "Cc: " CC_MAIL "\r\n",
  "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
  "rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
  "Subject: SMTP example message\r\n",
  "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */ 
  "The body of the message starts here.\r\n",
  "\r\n",
  "It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n",
  "Check RFC5322.\r\n",
  NULL
};
```

Here is the example: [cURL_SMTP_From_Code](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point you to https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/libcurl which describes the --libcurl option for the curl command.
When running curl with `--libcurl outfile.c`, it will save sample code to `outfile.c` demonstrating how to use libcurl in the same way that the curl command does.

The reason I share this is to help you know how to find out for yourself how to do what you want with libcurl. Hopefully, this will help answer any questions you may have down the road.