# Send mail from C++ program

Tags: c++, email

I am looking for the best way to send a mail from a C++ program.
I tried to look online to find some good solutions, but I could not find anything which satisfies my needs.

- Should use SMTP
- Should be able to send plaintext and html
- I should be able to include attachments
- Would be able to run on a windows system

I found this online: 
[Send Email with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298762/send-email-with-c)
But this does not seem to offer a good and complete approach.

I would prefer the most "standard" way. But if the only thing which can be done is a custom library, this is also an option. I am specifically looking for a way to do this in Qt or with Boost ASIO?

***Edit***
This is what i have found in the meantime: 
https://forum.qt.io/topic/29280/simple-tls-ssl-supported-smtp-client-for-qt5/23
https://github.com/xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5

Seems a good fit for my issue, but i would need to take a look.

Thanks a lot for your time,
Simon

Comment: Your question is asking for resources, so is *off-topic*. And it certainly is operating system specific

Comment: There is "Smtp-Client-for-Qt" on github

Comment: Where should I post this kind of question? It is quite hard to describe my approach if I have not decided which library to use.

Comment: Your question is *extremely* operating system specific in practice. So tell us about your OS, what documentation you have read, what library are you using, and ask some better question with an [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

It's a complex enough task that a library is the best call. libquickmail is a good call for something as simple as your use case. Curl also supports SMTP if you're familiar with that

Answer (score 0):

C++11 does not know about emails (check by reading [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), or trust me about that).

In practice, email sending could be [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific. You should read more about [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).

Have you considered using [vmime](https://www.vmime.org/) ? It is a C++ library which might fit your needs (at least on Linux & POSIX systems).

Comment: FWIW I have used vmime in the past and been pleased with the results.

Comment: Although I'm not sure that reading all of C++11 standardese is the best way to discover that C++ doesn't have email support ;)