# Running a python code in cpp or sending email using cpp

Tags: python, c++, email

So here's the case, i have been working on a project(c++), for which i need to send an email to the user. i had learnt how to do that in python during a  workshop but have no idea about how to do it in c++.
so i need help on how to set up email in cpp or run a python code via cpp.(Would prefer the later).

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137/calling-python-from-a-c-program-for-distribution

Comment: See the answers on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298762/send-email-with-attachment-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling python from a c++ program for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137/calling-python-from-a-c-program-for-distribution)